# Genymotion, unable to start virtual device

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I want to run a virtual device using genymotion. I have read all the reference docs in GenyMotion website and videos how to set up virtual device and run. I have here in all screen shots but still I have same error.

I have all the settings here in screenshots same as shown in different docs but still the same error. What am I missing ?

[image: nexus_5_info]

[image: nexus_5_network]

[image: nexus_5_start_error]

[image: adapter_network]

[image]ck.imgur.com/m79CE.png